# Python crashing while processing cursor

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, python

I have a fairly small script which is running a cursor on a small feature class (~2500 features) which is crashing python with a `python.exe has stopped working` message.

[image]

I have a cursor that loops over features, deletes any that don't meet a set criteria, looks up field value keys in a dictionary, and updates another field with the dictionary value.  This works well.  But if I add in a check to `deleteRow()` any records that have a `Null` or a value that doesn't start with the letter `O`.

```
arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(r"mydatabase.sde\mydatabase.dbo.SitePolygon", "in_memory", "xTempPolygon")

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(r'in_memory\xTempPolygon', ['RecID', 'LotID', 'Owner', 'Manager', 'Class']) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if row[2] != 'CITY' or row[4][:4].upper() == 'ROAD' or row[3].upper() in ['WASTEWATER', 'STORMWATER', 'WATERSUPPLY']:
            cursor.deleteRow()
        elif row[0] in resultDict:
            row[1] = resultDict[row[0]]
            cursor.updateRow(row)

        #################################################
        # If I add this block, it crashes
        if row[1] is None or row[1][0].upper() != 'O':
            cursor.deleteRow()
        #################################################
```

The `resultDict` is a dictionary that comes from a SQL lookup that returns `RecID` and `LotID`.  These are looked up in the cursor and populates the `LotID` on the feature based on its `RecID`.

If I leave out the final `if` block, it runs without issue.  If I add it in it crashes.  I need it there because I'm ending up with some records that have a `NULL` or a value that doesn't start with `O` in the `LotID` field.  I need these records deleted.

I need the extra `if` to run after the update to allow for the update to run, as no records have any values in `row[1]` before the update - they are all `NULL` so they'd all be deleted.

What is causing this crash, and how do I avoid it?

Comment: You may be accessing the row after it has been deleted.  If you have multiple flows that could delete, better to use a Boolean flag, then conditionally delete at the bottom of the loop.  Print statements would help clarify what is happening.

Comment: What if you change the block to an elif and move it above the update block?

Comment: @NateWanner I can't - I need it to run after the update to allow for the update to run (as none of them have values in `row[1]` before the update

Comment: @Vince you may be onto something.  I hadn't considered the fact that I was trying to access the row after it was deleted

Comment: @Vince If you would post that as an answer I'll accept it, as you pointed me right at the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @Vince and @NateWanner for two suggestions that pointed me in the right direction.

As @Vince had commented, I was trying to access a `row` that had been deleted.

I created an `else` block and moved my `elif` (and turned it into `if`) and the failing `if` block into the `else` so that it would only process on rows that hadn't yet been deleted.

```
arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(r"mydatabase.sde\mydatabase.dbo.SitePolygon", "in_memory", "xTempPolygon")

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(r'in_memory\xTempPolygon', ['RecID', 'LotID', 'Owner', 'Manager', 'Class']) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if row[2] != 'CITY' or row[4][:4].upper() == 'ROAD' or row[3].upper() in ['WASTEWATER', 'STORMWATER', 'WATERSUPPLY']:
            cursor.deleteRow()
        else:
            if row[0] in resultDict:
                row[1] = resultDict[row[0]]
                cursor.updateRow(row)
            if row[1] is None or row[1][0].upper() != 'O':
                cursor.deleteRow()
```

This is now working as desired, although thinking on the two comments further leads me to believe there may be even better ways to construct this cursor that'll I'll investigate.